# Firebase Cloud Function for Firestore does not work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I just switched from FirebaseDatabase to FireStore, so I have to rewrite some cloud functions to match with the FireStore syntax, but the problem is it does not work as the FirebaseDatabase one.

Here is my code:

```
exports.addMessageTest = functions.firestore.document('/messages/{id}').onCreate(async (req, res) => {

  const original = req.query.text;

  const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original});

  res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});

});
```

Basically, I want to trigger an event whenever there is a new document create in the declared path, but what I noticed is that the function never triggered even I tried:

1. create a new document directly in the database
2. using swift to create a new document (successfully created, but did not trigger the function) `try? db.collection("messages").document().setData(data)`

So what seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You are coding the `onCreate()` [background Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?hl=en#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created) for Firestore as an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?hl=en).

The `req` and `res` do not represent the Express.js request and response objects in a `onCreate()` background Cloud Function.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?hl=en#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created): The first argument of the callback function is a `DocumentSnapshot` representing the Firestore doc which triggered the CF and the second argument is the context of the CF.

Also, note that background CFs should be terminated in a different way compare to HTTPS CFs. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions?hl=en) for more details since correctly managing the life cycle of your CFs is very important.

Comment: I tried replacing the body of function with simple db.collection.add, but it still did not work whenever there is a new doc created. I also tried the sample onCreate() by firebase but it did not work too.